# Azure equivalent to Google Cloud IAP?

Tags: azure, authorization

> Cloud IAP works by verifying a user’s identity and determining if that user should be allowed to access the application.

Is there anything like this on Microsoft Azure?

Comment: Please take a look at Azure AD B2C (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) and Azure AD B2B.

Comment: Could you specify one scenario which you want to achieve?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I'd like to prevent anyone not in a specific Role/Group from being able to make requests to an internal HTTP endpoint.

Comment: Looks like this is now possible! https://stackoverflow.com/a/75410857/4303355

Answer (score 0):

This [medium article](https://rav3n.medium.com/drop-the-bastion-in-the-clouds-aws-azure-kinda-and-gcp-e589df7d4fec) that talks about how to "drop the bastion in the clouds" may be a good starting point.