# How to setup a similar Identify Aware Proxy from GCP in Azure

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, identity-aware-proxy

In GCP, it's easy to setup a IAP (hide your apps under a Google oAuth service). For more info: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart

Does Azure has something similar?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/active-directory-b2c/#features ??

Comment: Review Azure Active Directory P2. Azure AD P2 has more features/options than Google Context Aware Access.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some googling and discovered "Azure AD Application Proxy", it's pretty cool in that it can do what a normal authentication proxy can do and more (make on prem apps accessible w/o bastion/vpn). "After a single sign-on to Azure AD, users can access both cloud and on-premises applications through an external URL or an internal application portal."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy

This shows the UI interactions for an unauthenticated user:
https://youtu.be/Y-uTz7aXGd0?t=306

This shows the UI interactions for an authenticated user:
https://youtu.be/_2kWq5H4NhY?t=195

Comment: AFAIK Azure AD Application Proxy is only suitable for on premises applications and setup is quite complex: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this is now available with recent developments to the Bastion service, and to the Azure CLI. For me, it works as a drop in replacement in terms of user experience to GCP's IAP tunneling (but costs a minimum of £170 a month AFAICT).

I am running these commands from a host Ubuntu machine.

```
> uname -v
#64~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 16:42:31 UTC 2023
```

For example

```
> az network bastion tunnel \
  --name <bastion-name> \
  --resource-group <rg-name> \
  --target-resource-id /subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/dev/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<vm-with-no-public-ip> \
  --resource-port 22 --port 2222

Opening tunnel on port: 2222
Tunnel is ready, connect on port 2222
Ctrl + C to close
```

will enable me to set up VSCode remote against an Azure VM which doesn't have a private IP address through the bastion.

Also, there is a convenience command to SSH to the machine (which has an AD auth option)

```
akhil@host > az network bastion ssh \
  --name <bastion-name> \
  --resource-group <rg-name> \
  --target-resource-id /subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<vm-with-no-public-ip> \
  --auth-type ssh-key \
  --username akhil \
  --ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Command group 'az network' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1033-azure x86_64)

<login message>

akhil@<vm-with-no-public-ip>:~$
```

`az-cli` versions

```
> az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.45.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.45.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.8",
  "extensions": {
    "azure-devops": "0.18.0",
    "bastion": "0.2.1",
    "ssh": "1.1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not quite the same thing as GCP's IAP, I believe.

GCP's IAP allows you to log onto VMs - without SSH / RDP. The Azure App Proxy is mainly for app level authentication, correct? Not a replacement for SSH/RDP onto VMs.

Comment: IAP does not allow you to log into a server. IAP tunnels traffic securely into Google's network.